# moving binaries from bin to specific folder

Tags: files, software-installation, directory-structure

I want to install RNAhybrid tool so I downloaded it and configured it.
I wanted to keep in a directory called programs, so I downloaded the tar.gz in that directory, extracted it and then used following commands

```
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

When I used `which RNAhybrid` command it gives me

```
/usr/local/bin/RNAhybrid
```

How can I move this to `/home/user/programs/RNAhybrid_2.2/` folder so that everytime when i type which RNAhybrid it gives 
`/home/user/programs/RNAhybrid_2.2/RNAhybrid`

Answer (score 3):

First of all: this is your computer, so you can do anything with it that you want, so the commands to move it there are at the end of this rant.  **;-)**

**However,** the application is exactly where it's supposed to be according to the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/) and other applications that depend on this one will expect it there.  And it doesn't matter whether you're running Ubuntu, Debian, FreeBSD, HP-UX, AIX, Tru-64, or any other variant of Unix/Linux on the planet and beyond, they all have their version of `RNAhybrid` in that directory.

And this is only one application.  You'll want to do that with another and another and another and in the end you'll have backed yourself into a corner you will not be able to get yourself out of without re-installing everything and *then following the standard*.  But hey, if you want Ubuntu to be Windows (=a mess), just:

```
md /home/user/programs/RNAhybrid_2.2/
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/RNAhybrid /home/user/programs/RNAhybrid_2.2/
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and add `/home/user/programs/RNAhybrid_2.2/` to the end of the existing path.

Good luck!  (You'll need it...)